# Not able to animate using Funcanimation

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, matplotlib-animation

I am using code from geekforgeek and copying it to jupyternotebook.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation, writers
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (7,5))
axes = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
axes.set_ylim(0, 300)
palette = ['blue', 'red', 'green',
        'darkorange', 'maroon', 'black']

y1, y2, y3, y4, y5, y6 = [], [], [], [], [], []

def animation_function(i):
    y1 = i
    y2 = 5 * i
    y3 = 3 * i
    y4 = 2 * i
    y5 = 6 * i
    y6 = 3 * i

    plt.xlabel("Country")
    plt.ylabel("GDP of Country")
    
    plt.bar(["India", "China", "Germany",
            "USA", "Canada", "UK"],
            [y1, y2, y3, y4, y5, y6],
            color = palette)

plt.title("Bar Chart Animation")

animation = FuncAnimation(fig, animation_function,
                        interval = 50)
plt.show()
```

I am able to see only image not the animation. How to solve it?[this is what I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kt3hT.png)[this is what I should should get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLs67.png)

Comment: The animation itself works in matplotlib 3.5.1., so I assume it is a setting in jupyter notebook that prevents it from being animated.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to install the [`ipympl` module](https://github.com/matplotlib/ipympl). You can install it with `pip install ipympl` or with `conda install -c conda-forge ipympl`.

Then, when you need an interactive frame to wrap Matplotlib's output (such as is the case for animations), you execute the following command at the top of your notebook: `%matplotlib widget`.

Then, you execute your cell with the animation, and "magically" it will be rendered on the screen.